# assigning the value to a list inside a class

Tags: c#

I have following class. I have a list inside the class. How do I assign the values to the properties inside the list. Below is my code:

```
public class Identity
    {

        public Identity()
        {
            header = new List<Header>();
            control = new List<control>();
        }
        public List<Header> header { get; set; }
        public List<control> control{ get; set; }
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
  }
```

Below is the header class:

```
  public class Header
    {
        public string tenantId { get; set; }
        public string test2{ get; set; }
        public string test2{ get; set; }
    }
```

How can I assign the value of "Hello" to tenantId.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Since your class holds a list of `Header` objects, the question you should ask yourself first is "_which `tenantId` do I want to assign this value_".

After that, you can assign the value to the element on index `i` like so: `myIdentity.header[i].tenantId = "Hello";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your Identity contains list of header. Create an instance of Identity and Header. Then Assign the value to header class variables. And Header instance to list of Header.

```
var myIdentity = new Identity();
var myHeader = new Header();
myHeader.tenantId = "Hello";
myIdentity.Header.Add(myHeader);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Adding to list inside the Identity class
public class Identity
{
    public Identity()
    {
        header = new List<Header>();
        control = new List<control>();
    }
    public List<Header> header { get; set; }
    public List<control> control { get; set; }
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public void AddToHeader(string tenantIdParam)
    {
        var newHeaderObject = new Header
        {
            tenantId = tenantIdParam
        };

        header.Add(newHeaderObject);
    }
}

//Adding to the list outside the Identity class (since header is public and has a setter)
public class OtherClass
{
   public void DoSomething()
   {
      var identity = new Identity();

      var newHeaderObject = new Header
      {
         tenantId = tenantIdParam
      };

      identity.Header.Add(newHeaderObject);
   }
}
```